# iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight - Dart equivalent

Tags: dart, dart-html

```dart
final html.IFrameElement iframe = rootDemoElement.querySelector("iframe");
final int contentHeight = <???>.scrollHeight;
```

this works in JS:

```js
var contentHeight = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

contentDocument is not available in Dart.
Is it really possible that contentDocument is missing in Dart?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there was an attempt to make Dart in the browser more secure than JavaScript and this led to a model where cross-window communication was limited (to postMessage). I assume an Iframe suffers from the same limitations. There was a comment on an issue that they want to leave this strategy because this is usually circumnavigated by using dart-js-interop anyway.

I think the main culprit is that you get a `_DOMWindowCrossFrame` instead of a `Window` instance.

See

- http://dartbug.com/17936#c2

probably also related

- http://dartbub.com/20146
- http://dartbug.com/20143
- http://dartbug.com/20173
- http://dartbug.com/21219
- http://dartbug.com/20216
- http://dartbug.com/19610
- http://dartbug.com/16814
- http://dartbug.com/12788
- http://dartbug.com/2312

Comment: Great to hear it helped.  I hope they'll fix it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```dartlang
var jsIFrame = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(iframe);
var contentHeight = jsIFrame["contentDocument"]["documentElement"]["scrollHeight"];
```